# I am running DPDK packet Gen application. The application does not find any ports by itself and even If I try to add one it doesnt work?

Tags: network-programming, dpdk

http://pktgen.readthedocs.org/en/latest/running.html
This is the pktgen dpdk application. The screenshot in that link shows how ports are configured. But For me it doesnt configure at all. I am looking for help as a beginner

Answer (score 1):

First, as you may know, *pktgen* is an application that use the DPKD framework, thus, you should have bind at least one NIC to DPDK. Check the documentation about DPDK: [DPDK building instructions](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/build_dpdk.html). You should see your NIC correctly bound with this command:

```
# path/to/DPDK/tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py --status
```

Then, you can run *pktgen*. The ports you want to use are specified with the *-p*  option (It's a specific *pktgen* option so it's after the *--*). It's a port mask, so for instance, if you want only the first port (port 0) you can use *-p 0x1*.

Then, the *-m* option permit you to choose which core will handle which DPDK port. The syntax is not really obvious, I suggest you to read the doc of *pktgen* about this option: [pktgen command line options](https://pktgen.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage_pktgen.html).
For example, to be short, the option *-m "[1:3].0*" says you want that CPU core 1 handle "RX port 0", and CPU core 3 handle "TX port 0".

A simple command line for *pktgen*, if you use only one port running on two cores could be:

```
./app/pktgen -c 0x7 -n 3 -- -p 0x1 -P -m "[1:2].0"
```

In that case CPU core 1 and 2 (possible because of the "-c 0x7 option") will be used to handle respectively RX and TX of port 0 (configured with "-p 0x1"). Note that -P is for promiscuous mode.

Comment: I did bind the NIC card to DPDK IGB_UIO driver. It detected the presence of one port but still it didnt configure.

Comment: sudo ./app/build/pktgen -c 0x10 -n 2 -- -P -m 1.0

Comment: I have got the application running. But it says the 
Port  0: Link Down <Enable promiscuous mode>

and because of that I am still not able to run the application. I dont see the any signs of packets... No statistics on the application

Comment: You are missing the "-p 0x1" after the --